# asp.net: display data in gridview or listview or other data control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

It's been a while since I've used the data controls in asp.net, so here goes.

My tsql query returns this datatable:

```
State          City            First              Last        
----------------------------------------------------------
Florida        Miami           Bob                Jones   
Florida        Miami           Joe                James
Florida        Miami           Mary               Hart
Florida        Miami           Jane               Smith
Florida        Orlando         Tina               Karl
Florida        Orlando         George             Williams 
Florida        Orlando         Ralph              Davis
```

I want some simple data control that will display the data like so, without much hassle. I simply don't want to repeat the state/city for every row:

```
Florida      Miami
      Bob                Jones   
      Joe                James
      Mary               Hart
      Jane               Smith
Florida      Orlando
      Tina               Karl
      George             Williams 
      Ralph              Davis
```

Comment: Are you looking for a recommendation or something?  Because that's not On Topic here.  However, if you update your question with the code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, along with an explanation of where in that code you're not getting the results you expect, then you'd likely have an On Topic question we can answer

Comment: Telerik has a UI grid. You've tagged this with Telerik. Are you asking which of their controls you should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use a listview.

You can do it like this:

First, use the wizard to lay out the listview (create it for you).

Delete all the templates - only leave in the item template.

So this is what the result is:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td><asp:Label ID="ProvinceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">
                            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr runat="server" style="">
                                    <th runat="server">Province</th>
                                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

The code to load up the grid? So far we have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
        loadGrid();
}

public void loadGrid()
{
    string strSQL;
    strSQL = "SELECT Province, City, HotelName, FirstName, LastName from tblHotels ORDER BY Province, City";
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        ListView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Ok, so we assume that the first two columns ARE ordered correctly as per above.

but, now lets add a grouping to the above.

Our item template thus becomes this:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

              <tr id="MyGroupHeading" runat="server" style="display:normal">

                        <td><asp:Label ID="Province" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Province") %>' /></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
             </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
            </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>
```

So, note how we just added a "tr" (table row)

Now, we can hide/show this extra header like this:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
ListViewDataItem LvRow = e.Item;
if (LvRow.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    var strNewGroup = (Label)LvRow.FindControl("Province").Text;
    strNewGroup += "*" + (Label)LvRow.FindControl("City").Text;

    HtmlTableRow MyTr = (HtmlTableRow)LvRow.FindControl("MyGroupHeading");
    if (strNewGroup != strMyGroup)
    {
        // a new group - 
        strMyGroup = strNewGroup;
        MyTr.Style("display") = "normal";
    }
    else
        MyTr.Style("display") = "none";
}
}
```

So  we really just manual code though this. The results now look like this;

[image]

And formatting? Well, if I drop my default css table format, then I get/see this:

[image]

And I suppose, if we wanted, we could pull left the sub group.

```
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
```

Change the above col span from 2 to 1, or even remove the col span.

Comment: Thank you. I had to make a few changes to the code, but worked like a charm.